# Use full URL as saved file name with wget

Tags: terminal, wget

I'm using wget in terminal to download a large list of images.

example — `$ wget -i images.txt`

I have all the image URLS in the images.txt file.

However, the image urls tend to be like `example.com/unqiueNumber/images/main_250.jpg`

which means that all the images come out named `main_250.jpg`

What I really need is the images to be saved with the entire URLs for the images for each one, so that the 'unique number' is part of the filenames.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `-x` option will force creation of subdirectories to match the url. e.g. `wget -x http://example.com/foo/bar/baz.txt` would write the local file to `./foo/bar/baz.txt`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that'll be helpful... i would need the image to be named like...`example.com-unqiueNumber-images-main_250.jpg`
`

Comment: that's above/beyond what wget is intended for. probably best option would be to run your file of urls through awk/sed-type things and process the urls into both urls + output file specification, then it's `wget url -O file_to_save_to`

Comment: is it possible to do `wget url -0 file_to_save_to` with a big batch? Or will I have to do one at once

Comment: unless you're running it in spidering mode, wget basically fetches urls one at a time. you can't really provide multiple urls and multiple `-O` options. so it'd be (in non-functional pseudocode) `cat urls|awk blahblahblah -exec wget $url -O $mangled_file`

Answer (score 5):

Presuming the urls for the images are in a text file named images.txt with one url per line you can run 
`cat images.txt | sed 'p;s/\//-/g' | sed 'N;s/\n/ -O /' | xargs wget`
to download each and every image with a filename that was formed out of the url.

Now for the explanation:

in this example I'll use 
`https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg
https://www.moooi.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/product-images/random_detail.jpg?itok=ErJveZTY` 
as images.txt (you can add as many images as you like to your file, as long as they are in this same format).

- `cat images.txt` pipes the content of the file to standard output
- `sed 'p;s/\//-/g'` prints the file to stdout with the url on one line and then the intended filename on the next line, like so:
  `https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg
  https:--www.newton.ac.uk-files-covers-968361.jpg
  https://www.moooi.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/product-images/random_detail.jpg?itok=ErJveZTY
  https:--www.moooi.com-sites-default-files-styles-large-public-product-images-random_detail.jpg?itok=ErJveZTY`
- `sed 'N;s/\n/ -O /'` combines the two lines of each image (the url and the intended filename) into one line and it adds the -O option inbetween (this is for wget to know that the second argument is the intended filename), the result for this part looks like this:
  `https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/covers/968361.jpg -O https:--www.newton.ac.uk-files-covers-968361.jpg
  https://www.moooi.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/product-images/random_detail.jpg?itok=ErJveZTY -O https:--www.moooi.com-sites-default-files-styles-large-public-product-images-random_detail.jpg?itok=ErJveZTY`
- and finally `xargs wget` runs wget for each line as the option, the endresult in this example is two images in the current directory named `https:--www.newton.ac.uk-files-covers-968361.jpg` and `https:--www.moooi.com-sites-default-files-styles-large-public-product-images-random_detail.jpg?itok=ErJveZTY` respectively.

Comment: But if you try to download a bunch of index.html pages from different domains, it will dump them into a single file which is then named after the last one. Try `https://google.com`, `https://bing.com`, `https://duckduckgo.com` as your input file. OP probably wanted a solution to be able to identify the source of the downloaded files.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
cat images.txt | parallel wget -O '{= s:/:-:g; =}' {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a not so elegant solution, that may not work everywhere.

You probably know that if your URL ends in a query, wget will use that query in the filename. e.g. if you have `http://domain/page?q=blabla`, you will get a file called `page?q=blabla` after download. Usually, this is annoying, but you can turn it to your advantage.

Suppose, you wanted to download some `index.html` pages, and wanted to keep track of their origin, as well as, avoid ending up with `index.html`, `index.html.1`, `index.html.2`, etc. in your download folder. Your input file `urls.txt` may look something like the following:

```
https://google.com/
https://bing.com/
https://duckduckgo.com/
```

If you call `wget -i urls.txt` you end up with those numbered index.html files. But if you "doctor" your urls with a fake query, you get useful file names.

Write a script that appends each url as a query to itself, e.g.

```
https://google.com/?url=https://google.com/
https://bing.com/?url=https://bing.com/
https://duckduckgo.com/?url=https://duckduck.com/
```

Looks cheesy, right? But if you now execute `wget -i urls.txt`, you get the following files:

```
index.html?url=https:%2F%2Fbing.com%2F
index.html?url=https:%2F%2Fduckduck.com%2F
index.html?url=https:%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F
```

instead of non-descript numbered `index.html`s. Sure, they look ugly, but you can clean up the filenames, and voilà! Each file will have its origin as its name.

The approach probably has some limitations, e.g. if the site you are downloading from actually executes the query and parses the parameters, etc.

Otherwise, you'll have to solve the file name/source url problem outside of `wget`, either with a bash script or in other programming languages.